# Run application on the older iphone os

Tags: iphone, sdk

my new app update runs only on 3.1.3 OS and some people who have older os [3.1.2] can't run the application on the iphone .. does it way to solve this ? and my app runs on 3.1.2 iphone os?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more specific on Franci's answer:

You need to set the Deployment Target build setting in your target's settings. Set it to the lowest version of iPhone OS you wish to support.

After doing this, you should always compile your app against the latest SDK, to benefit from bug fixes and performance improvments.

If you use any features from the latest SDK that aren't available on prior OS versions, you should weakly link to the framework in which that feature is defined, and use conditional checks to see if the API exists before using it. If the API doesn't exist at runtime, your app should gracefully fall back onto a default behaviour.

If your app doesn't use any APIs which are not in prior OS versions then you don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebuild your app update targeting the 3.1.2 OS and resubmit to the AppStore. You also need to isolate any 3.1.3-specific features you are using.